# Ubuntu not booting (want to bypass hardware failure)

Tags: boot, 20.04, integrated

Recently, I found out that I have an issue with my laptop GPU hardware. Since I have the integrated graphics (Intel+AMD), the only solution I got is the replacement of the motherboard. My Windows OS is crashing even after a fresh install. I tried installing Ubuntu **(normal mode)** the installation setup doesn't even load up, it just sticks at a black screen. Then I tried Ubuntu **(safe graphics mode)** for installation and luckily it worked. After installation when I tried to boot into Ubuntu it does not load (stuck at loading screen). I don't know much about hardware stuff but at least I can say that it is not booting up because of that integrated GPU hardware failure (since my SSD and RAM are working fine).

I somehow got a way to boot into Ubuntu: **Booting into Ubuntu (recovery mode) -> option of resume to normal boot**. Luckily it worked and I successfully booted into my Ubuntu and it is working perfectly fine.

I don't know how it worked or how it bypassed the failure error. I don't care about integrated graphics hardware or driver and want to use my Ubuntu for normal work only. Is there any way I can normally boot up my Ubuntu from GRUB instead of every time going to recovery mode and booting up from there. I don't want to replace my whole motherboard and want it to just work with normal setup (without integrated graphics). Can someone please guide, it will be a very big help! Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to access the grub menu during boot-up with hitting `e`? You could try to set the `nomodeset` option and if it works you could config your system to boot with these settings by default. If you can not access the grub menu you could change the setting with booting the way you described from the running system and update your grub with `sudo update-grub` before rebooting. Or from recovery. Just type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` if you installed in non UEFI mode.

Comment: @starkus Yes, I am able to access the grub menu. Could you tell how and what "nodemodeset" setting I have to configure?

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling about this! https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu This thing worked for me and now I can normally boot up my Ubuntu :)

Comment: Can I suggest one of you posts the solution as an answer? Looks like you’ve solved it - would help others to have a full answer.